# Find the component of $y\in \prod_{\alpha}Y_{\alpha}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Find the component of $y\in \prod_{\alpha}Y_{\alpha}$

**My work**

I know the component of $x$ is the union of all subset connected contain $x$

I don't have a clear idea of how attack this exercise. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't put "my work" if you have done no work. It's fine to ask a question that you don't know how to approach. And it's a good idea to indicate what you think you *should* do. But it's not something you can call "work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of connected spaces is connected, so if $y_\alpha$ has connected  component $C_\alpha(y_\alpha) \subseteq Y_\alpha$, for all $\alpha$ we have that

$$C(y):= \prod_\alpha C_\alpha(y_\alpha)$$ is connected. And if $C$ is any connected set that contains $y$, $\pi_\alpha[C]$ is connected and contains $y_\alpha$ so by maximality of components :

$$\forall \alpha: \pi_\alpha[C] \subseteq C_\alpha(y_\alpha)$$ which implies

$$C \subseteq C(y)$$ We can conclude that $C(y)$ is the connected component of $y$ in $\prod_\alpha Y_\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is clear. But i don't understand this step. $\forall \alpha: \pi_\alpha[C] \subseteq C_\alpha(y_\alpha)$. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Bvss12 This uses that a component (of $y_\alpha$) is a maximal connected set (see my other answer to your other question). As I said, $\pi_\alpha[C]$ is connected (as projections are continuous), contains $y_\alpha$ (as  $y \in C$) and is thus contained in the component of $y_\alpha$, which is the union of all connected subsets containing $y_\alpha$.